# Zip files which are located in IsolatedStorage

Tags: c#, silverlight, isolatedstorage, sharpziplib

My application need to download multiple files in Silverlight, and because I don't want to ask user multiple times for permission to save the files, I save the files in IsolatedStorage first and then I want to zip them all to a file and ask once for saving permission.

therefore I used SharpZipLib to zip multiple files which are located in IsolatedStorage, the problem is that SharpZipLib just accept file address as ZipEntery:

```
ZipEntry z= new ZipEntry(name);
```

and as you know cause the files are located in IsolatedStorage I don't have the address of them.

I saw sample on [Create a Zip from/to a memory stream or byte array](http://wiki.sharpdevelop.net/SharpZipLib-Zip-Samples.ashx) but I cant use it for multiple files.

Please help me to find a way to use SharpZipLib or introduce me another way to downloading multiple files without asking multiple times for permission.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `name` in `ZipEntry z= new ZipEntry(name);` is a logical/relative name inside your zip, you can establish it any way you want.

So as long as you can re-open you IsoStorage files as a Stream, you should be able to use SharpZip.